# Prepopulated Database Kotlin

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin

I need some help. I have a database created by DB Browser SQLite. I wanna use it in app. It has 1441 english words and translations. I want to show them on TextView in a loop by onclicklistener. But I am new to Room Database and Kotlin. I check emulator data and there is my Vocubulary database is created.

Here is my MainActivity :

```
 val database = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "Vocabulary")
            .createFromAsset("database/myapp.db")
            .build()
    database.dao().readWord()
    database.dao().readFirstTranslation()
    database.dao().readSecondTranslation()
```

Entity :

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity
class Word_Entity {
@PrimaryKey
var voc_id: Int = 0
@ColumnInfo(name = "Vocabulary")
var vocs: String = ""
@ColumnInfo(name = "FirstTranslation")
var meaningFirst = ""
@ColumnInfo(name = "SecondTranslation")
var meaningSecond= ""
}
```

AppDatabase:

```
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
@Database(entities =[(Word_Entity::class)], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun dao () : DAO
}
```

DAO:

```
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface DAO {
@Query("select * from Word_Entity where Vocabulary")
fun readWord (): List<Word_Entity>
@Query("select * from Word_Entity where FirstTranslation")
fun readFirstTranslation (): List<Word_Entity>
@Query("select * from Word_Entity where SecondTranslation")
fun readSecondTranslation (): List<Word_Entity>
}
```

Comment: The answer you're looking for is unclear.  Would you please better define the question?

Comment: I couldnt find any tutorial about how to prepopulate room database. I also not sure about my coding above. All tutorials are about creating room and adding single data. I can't add 1400 variables one by one. That's really time wasting. 
1. How to prepopulate Room Database
2. How to reach to my database 
3. How to take them in a loop 
4. How to show them on TextView (TextView for each one: Word, first translation and second translation)
5. I also want to add a button. When user click the button app will show the next Word on a textview. Meaning of it will be on another textview.

Thanks.